# Y co-ordinate of a turtle coming up as a method instead of an integer python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have tried changing it to all be in one line so `bullet.sety(bullet.ycor()+20` but the same error message appears. I have also tried `bullet.sety(int(y)+20)` but it has an error message which says it can't turn a method into an integer.

```
def shoot_bullet():
   stop = "no"
   while True:
        y = bullet.ycor()
        bullet.sety(y+20)
        wn.update()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        if bullet.ycor > 293:
            stop = "yes"
        if stop == "yes":
            break
            bullet.goto(main_ship.xcor, main_ship.ycor)
```

The error message was

```
File "C:\Python\spaceinvaders.py", line 46, in shoot_bullet
bullet.sety(y+20)
TypeError: unsupported opperand type for +: 'method' and 'int'#
```

(It's only formatted as code because otherwise Stack Overflow marked it as an error)

Comment: Have you tried `type(y)` or even `y()`?

Comment: What does `bullet.ycor()` return? Perhaps you could show the code for that method.

Comment: If bullet,ycor() is returning a number you might want to cast it to an int: int(y)+20. As you have not posted "bullet" I can't say for sure though.

Comment: @Troma78 Obviously, it doesn't return a number, but a method.

Comment: @glglgl You are correct; I must need more coffee...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose what you describe happens in the 2nd loop run.

While you don't show us the code for `bullet`, I suspect the following:

`bullet.goto(main_ship.xcor, main_ship.ycor)` just sets the `x` and `y` fields in the `bullet` object to what you pass. As you just pass `main_ship.xcor` and `main_ship.ycor` (i. e. the methods instead of what they return), these are put into the bullet and returned on the `ycor()` call.

Solution: Do `bullet.goto(main_ship.xcor(), main_ship.ycor())` in order to call these methods.

As a side remark, instead of `stop = "no"` and `stop = "yes"`, it would be much better to use booleans for this purpose (`stop = False` and `stop = True`).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `bullet.ycor()` returns a method instead of a value of some method's call.

I guess your code can look like:

```
class Bullet:
    def some_method(self):
        ...

    def ycor(self):
        return self.some_method
```

but it should be

```
class Bullet:
    def some_method(self):
        ...

    def ycor(self):
        return self.some_method()
```

Mind the parenthesis.